# Subset data and plotting in R

Tags: r, plot, subset

I would like to use R to simplify and subset large datasets (over 100 000 values) and then plot them. Below is a simplified version of my dataset (Figure 1) where I broke it down into three years and two crop types. I have a Year (2011-2013), two crop types (Corn and Soybean) and their total Area.

I want to subset the data into the total Area of Corn and Soybean by year into a new table(example figure 2) with the year, type and total area and then plot the total area by year for each (example of plot in Figure 3).

[image]

Figure 1 Small example dataset

[image]

Figure 2 New total table

[image: small data sample]

Figure 3 example of graph that I want to produce

I thought I could subset the data by year and crop with

corn2011 <- subset(CropTable, Year==2011 & Lulc=="Corn")

corn2012 <- subset(CropTable, Year==2012 & Lulc=="Corn")

and then I can summarize the data using the sum function

sum(corn2011[,3]),

but I'm not sure how to plot them yearly or against each other to have it look like Figure 3.

Comment: we don't have access to your dataset. A reproducible example would be useful (use dput()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your plot, you could try this

```
data.df <- read.table(text="
   Year            Type Area
1       2011 corn  30
2       2012 corn  15
3       2013 corn  50
4       2011 Soy  45
5       2012 Soy  30
6       2013 Soy  60",
  header = TRUE)

ggplot(data=data.df, aes(x=as.factor(Year), y=Area, group=Type, color=Type)) + geom_line() + xlab("Year") + ylab("Area (ha)") + theme_bw() + scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that works for my figure 2, solves my main question. Now I just need to figure how summarize my data from Figure 1 to Figure 2.

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer:) and try Fig2Dataset <- Fig1Dataset %>% group_by(Year, Type) %>% summarise(AreaSum = sum(Area)

Comment: Will do also I think that will work but what does %>% stand for?

Comment: it's a pipe operator and it's really useful. you can learn more about that operator here http://www.r-statistics.com/2014/08/simpler-r-coding-with-pipes-the-present-and-future-of-the-magrittr-package/

Comment: Awesome thanks alot :) needed the ("ggplot2"), ("dplyr") and ("magrittr") packages but now it works for the sample dataset XD